# Multiprocessing with generators in fit_generator

Tags: keras

I have a generator yielding overlapping audio chunks extracted from long audio files. For large overlap ratio, the number of chunks can be huge, so I would like to avoid writing each of them to new files (e.g. an overlap of 90% means 10 times the original data size, which is already huge).

I want to use fit_generator to yield minibatches with some data augmentation processing, and I would like this processing to be executed on several processes. According to [the documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/), the first argument must be a [`keras.utils.Sequence`](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence), which *guarantees the ordering and guarantees the single use of every input per epoch when using use_multiprocessing=True*.
Unfortunately, this object must be initialized with the complete list of training examples, or path to the training examples.

So it seems that I cannot use `fit_generator` with a generator + multiprocessing? I'm left with either using a generator and no multiprocessing, or using a [`keras.utils.Sequence`](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) with all my audio chunks in separate files.

Am I right?

Comment: What makes you think it has to be initialized with a complete list of training examples? That is just wrong.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I guessed so because `keras.utils.Sequence` must implement `def __getitem__(self, index)` and the length must be known to implement `def __len__(self)`. And because I do not see how the `shuffle` argument of `fit_generator` can work otherwise.

Comment: Yes but that means you need to be able to index your batches, not to load them at once. You should be able to index them, no matter how complex is the data augmentation.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I still do not see how the shuffle could work without having access to the complete dataset. Do you have any pointer to examples of `keras.utils.Sequence` fed by a generator?

Comment: You shuffle indices from 0 to len() and then fetch the shuffled indices one by one from the sequence.